# My PC gets a blue screen when booting Windows installation Wizard through a bootable USB

Tags: windows-10, bios, bsod, windows-installation, bootable-media

I finished building my first ever PC build about 5 days ago now and since then, I've not been able to boot a Windows bootable USB to install Windows 10 without getting a blue screen in a matter of seconds after the installation wizard for windows appears. I asked for help on the Linus Tech Tips Forum and Reddit and so far have tried everything suggested to me and haven't had the issue fixed. here's the original Linus Tech Tips post: https://linustechtips.com/topic/1411266-blue-screen-when-booting-windows-installation-media-through-a-usb/ and here's a video of what happens when I try to boot through the USB: https://youtu.be/JxG1TnU1XNw (I no longer get the jumbled mess of a visual glitch for reasons I will get to)

I believe nothing is wrong with any of the hardware because all the parts are detected and seem to be working correctly in the Bios. Not only that, but through one of the suggestions I got in the original post, I managed to get Ubuntu (Linux) working easily with another USB without an issue and I'm currently using the PC in Ubuntu right now to make this post, proving there isn't anything wrong with the hardware.

Here's everything I've tried so far that didn't work (not necessarily in this order):

1. Tried using it on a different USB port.
2. Used another USB as the bootable device in case it was an issue with the USB itself.
3. Tried installing it to the hard drive instead of the SSD.
4. Downloaded a new copy of Windows Installation Media from the official site, formatted the USB, and reinstalled it onto said USB in case there was an issue with the Installation Media itself.
5. Downloaded a Windows 10 ISO and used the third-party program Rufus to install it to the USB instead of the official Windows Installation Media program.
6. Tried with secure boot turned both off and on in the Bios settings
7. Updated the Bios to the latest version (updating the Bios fixed the visual glitch during loading but didn't fix the blue screen crash issue).
8. I changed the UEFI mode to CSM in the settings (Locked me out of the Bios so be careful)

I believe that's everything I've tried but I will update this post if I remember something else I tried already.

My PC Specs:

Motherboard: MSI MPG B550 Gaming Edge Wifi

CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3600

GPU: AMD Radeon RX 6600

Ram: G.Skill Aegis 16GB (2 8GB sticks)

Power Supply: Antec Earthwatts Gold Pro 650W

Can somebody please help me with this because I feel like the person at Linus Tech Tips Forums may have given up on me.

Comment: Different operating systems use the hardware in different ways. The fact that Linux works does not mean that Windows must also work. The problem is either hardware or a missing driver that you may need to slipstream into the Windows installation media. See your motherboard downloads [here](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/MPG-B550-GAMING-EDGE-WIFI/support#down-bios).

Comment: The graphical artifacts before you were in the WinPE point to the GPU being the problem. WinPE doesn’t have the same kernel protection against crashes caused by the display driver

Comment: I highly believe you didn't install your PC correctly, probably you didn't read if your motherboard is compatible with other components of the machine. And to say in step 8. that don't boot to CMS is just wrong information. I would highly downvote this question.

Comment: Harrymc. Well I said that Linux working means Windows should too because that's what Master Disaster said in the Link I provided but thanks for letting me know that it's not necessarily the case. Also, i'll look into how to "slipstream" the drivers into the Installation Media, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Ramhound. But like I pointed out. I no longer get the graphical artefacts after updating to the latest Bios version. I also ran some tests on the GPU by downloading some steam games on Ubuntu. Not exactly the most graphically demanding games, being Edge, Geometry Dash, and Slime Rancher but I'm running low on internet data and can't download anything big for now. here's Slime Rancher running perfectly on my PC through Ubuntu with no graphical glitches or crashes https://youtu.be/3CaWNSWT8Jc

Comment: Satoshi. Yes, The PC is installed correctly and all the parts work correctly. Why would I not read up on whether all the parts are compatible with each other?. Also, why would you downvote somebody for having false information when they themselves are literally the one who is asking for help? That's just stupid. Not only that, but I clearly stated my reason for not suggesting to change to CSM which is quite a fair reason.. It locked me out of the Bios menu and the only way of resetting it was to short the MB's battery, though I found a seemingly undocumented online workaround for it.

Comment: I still think it's a hardware issue. Better just try to start ruling things out until you find the faulty component. For instance, in the case of RAM, remove one stick and keep the other, if the problem persists, put the first one back and remove the second one. Your motherboard also has on-board graphics, so try removing the GPU. Continue removing devices one at a time until the problem no longer reproduces, then you know what you may need to replace.

Comment: Hey Dan. I've had the problem for 10 months now and a lot has happened since. Not once have I had a hardware issue with my PC. I've used Ubuntu in the beginning, moved to Manjaro in April, and have played with many other Linux distro's since I posted this. Not once have I had a single hardware issue. The parts aren't faulty. I finally got virtualbox working now (long last) and Windows 10 even blue screens with system service exception in the virtual machine while trying to install. Tried Fedora in the virtual machine and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar situation and it drove me crazy! Finally solved it! Here was the initial problem: When I try to install Windows 10 or Windows 11 from a USB stick, I get a blue screen and a blinking cursor and then the installation fails. I have a new SSD drive and 8GB of RAM. The installation doesn’t even proceed to the point where it informs me the system is not supported or doesn’t meet the requirements. The screen just shows a blue screen with a blinking or flashing cursor. I have seen many suggestions to disable secure boot, but my HP ALL IN ONE is a 2011 machine and doesn’t even have that option in the BIOS settings.

Solution:  The key is to NOT use the UEFI boot option. Instead choose Legacy > Hard Drive > USB disk name… and boom the installation is now working and is at 100% now! I will update the forum if needed. Attached is the BIOS setting I chose. Hope it helps someone else.

Images from BIOS boot menu below…

https://postimg.cc/gallery/NmJp7Rv

[Boot Choices in BIOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQV1f.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's quite late to answer this, but this could help people googling.

I had the same problem as you, only solution that worked for me was:

- Disable secure boot in bios
- Disable fast boot in bios
- Allow both uefi and csm boot(in my case my bios allowed me to choose from
  3 options: Only uefi - only csm - both uefi and csm).
- Make a bootable usb using some app like Rufus, choose MBR partition, not GPT.

Then boot from usb and it should work.